# Microsoft Graph SDK: documentation for older versions

Tags: java, documentation, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have to use the `Microsoft Graph Java SDK` version `5.x`, but I cannot find a copy of the official documentation for older versions of the SDKs and version `6.x` has some method that work differently.

Is there a way to get a copy of the old docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should a branch for SDK v5 in the GitHub repo

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/tree/support/5.x.x

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/tree/v5.80.0

But I'm not sure whether is enough for you.